# Angular 2way binding for username and username_confirm

Tags: html, angular

I have the following problem, I download the username from the server as username field, I display it in the following form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-material" #updateUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateUser(updateUserForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-12">Username: </label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input name="username" type="text" #username="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.username"
          class="form-control form-control-line" required [disabled]="notEditMode" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!notEditMode">
      <label class="col-md-12">Confirm username: </label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input name="confirm_username" type="text" #username_confirm="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.username"
          class="form-control form-control-line" required [disabled]="notEditMode" />
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="updateUserForm.value.username !== updateUserForm.value.confirm_username">
          Username don't match.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And now I would like to make the username and confirm_username insert the username value from the server, but when I edit the username field in the form, the confirm_username field should not be bound based on username.

In general, I want the user to complete the confirm_username field with the same value after changing the username.

Currently the code above works in such a way that when I change the username value, it also changes to confirm_username, and I want the user to confirm the username itself.

Comment: You have to use two different controls for each fields.. like instead of [ngModel]="user.username" use [ngModel]="user.confirmusername"

Answer (score 1):

You should use different ngModel names, in the above code you used the same ngModel name for both the input fields.

```
<input name="confirm_username" type="text" #username_confirm="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.confirmusername" class="form-control form-control-line"
                required [disabled]="notEditMode" />
```

Comment: That's right, but I would like the value of confirm_username to be the same as the username by default.

Comment: I added a second field and everything works. I only have one more problem, in case the username is different than username_confirm, the "Username do not match." Error appears to me, but I can still send the form normally despite the fact that it does not validate 100%.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the code above works in such a way that when I change the username value, it also changes to confirm_username

Of course: You are binding to the same field.

You need to have another field for the confirmed field. If that doesn't come from the server, just add a local field in your component, copy the default user name from server into it and bind to that local field.

Comment: I added a second field and everything works. I only have one more problem, in case the username is different than username_confirm, the "Username do not match." Error appears to me, but I can still send the form normally despite the fact that it does not validate 100%.

Comment: Did you put the condition if the form is valid on the submit button or submit function of the form? Otherwise the form does not know it is invalid. Or you can use validator, they will communicate the unmet condition to the form directly.